# The recipient will be replaced with default from

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

This is an strange problem,

At first I could send my mail via mailgun,

But now the expected recipient `bill.email` will be replaced with `me@#{ENV['mailgun_domain']}`

I totally have no idea. because the code not changed

```
class BillMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@#{ENV['mailgun_domain']}"
  def confirm_bill(bill, cart)
    mail(to: bill.email, cc: "poc7667@gmail.com")
  end
end
```

I printed the `mail` object, everything looks fine

```
#<Mail::Message:70158682584200, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: balance@4am-lesson.com>, <To: test_123@gmail.com>, <Cc: test_123@gmail.com>, <Subject: hihi>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
```

But when I checked the mailgun log, my recipient was replaced with `balance_coffe@sandboxc88b11b1bddf4594aad351f79e76d6ba.mailgun.org`, it supposed be my default sent from, I thought it a mailgun bug

```
 "message": {
    "headers": {
      "to": "balance_coffe@sandboxc88b11b1bddf4594aad351f79e76d6ba.mailgun.org",
      "message-id": "20150503112244.C04DC5995993@Poc-MacBook-Pro-Retina-15-2013-late-2.local",
      "from": "MAILER-DAEMON@Poc-MacBook-Pro-Retina-15-2013-late-2.local (Mail Delivery System)",
      "subject": "Undelivered Mail Returned to Sender"
    },
    "attachments": [],
    "recipients": [
      "balance_coffe@sandboxc88b11b1bddf4594aad351f79e76d6ba.mailgun.org"
    ],
    "size": 20919
  },
  "recipient": "balance_coffe@sandboxc88b11b1bddf4594aad351f79e76d6ba.mailgun.org",
  "event": "accepted"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly valid behavior.  If you observe your `from` and `subject` attributes in your log, you'll see, your smtp server (OSX default) is trying to tell you about a failure mail delivery.  This is what an SMTP server will do if it cannot deliver an email to the recipient.

To fix this, you'll need to configure SMTP setting for your rails app.  Add the following in your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :authentication => :plain,
  :address => "smtp.mailgun.org",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "MYDOMAIN.mailgun.org",
  :user_name => "postmaster@MYDOMAIN.mailgun.org",
  :password => "MYPASSWORD"
}
```

Replace `:domain`, `:username` and `:password` with your mailgun credentials.